# Efficiently passing additional information per group to Dask dataframe.groupby.apply function

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a Dask dataframe that is grouped, and then a function is applied to each group. That function uses some pre-calculated metrics from another dataframe as part of its work.

In the actual code, all the data is in parquet datasets loaded from S3 and run on a distributed Dask cluster. Here's a simplified example using csv files.

**profiles.csv**

```
company,stat1
1000,10
2000,20
```

**catalog.csv**

```
company,desc
1000,ABC
1000,def
2000,GHI
2000,jkl
```

**code**

```
from dask import dataframe as ddf

profiles_df = ddf.read_csv("profiles.csv").set_index("company")
catalog_df = ddf.read_csv("catalog.csv").set_index("company")

def refine(group_df):
    profile = profiles_df.loc[group_df.name].compute()
    group_df["desc_"] = group_df["desc"].apply(lambda t: f"{t}-{int(profile.stat1)}")
    return group_df

catalog_grouped_df = catalog_df.groupby("company")
refined_catalog_meta = catalog_df._meta.copy()
refined_catalog_meta["desc_"] = None
refined_catalog_df = catalog_grouped_df.apply(refine, meta=refined_catalog_meta)
refined_catalog_df.compute()
```

This works, except that the source `profiles_df` csv/parquet is being read over and over again for each invocation of `refine(group_df)`. How do I improve this so that `profiles_df` is read once, and then only the row is relevant for each group is passed to or accessed by the `refine` function?

**Update**

I've managed to stop the repeated reads from the source Parquet datasets by reading the profiles_df and scattering it. Something like this

```
from dask import dataframe as ddf
from dask.distributed import default_client

profiles_df = ddf.read_csv("profiles.csv").set_index("company")
catalog_df = ddf.read_csv("catalog.csv").set_index("company")

def refine(group_df):
    profile = profiles_df.loc[group_df.name].compute()
    group_df["desc_"] = group_df["desc"].apply(lambda t: f"{t}-{int(profile.stat1)}")
    return group_df

profiles_df = default_client().scatter(profiles_df.compute(), broadcast=True)
catalog_grouped_df = catalog_df.groupby("company")
refined_catalog_meta = catalog_df._meta.copy()
refined_catalog_meta["desc_"] = None
refined_catalog_df = catalog_grouped_df.apply(refine, meta=refined_catalog_meta)
refined_catalog_df.compute()
…
```

The main downside is that `profiles_df` is being read to the calling client and then sent to the scheduler. Is there a way I can get the scheduler or a worker to do the read and scatter?

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've tried to make a mcve that demonstrates this. It's hard to demonstrate the effect without the large original parquet datasets.